# how to reindex object start from 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures

I have an object output from below code how to set the index start from 0 in js?

```
Object
  3: Object
     id: 34
     type: 0


var obj = {};
var edited = false;
for (var i = 0; i < $(".list").length; i++) {
  var data_id = parseInt($(".list").eq(i).attr('data-id'));
  var data_type = parseInt($(".list").eq(i).attr('data-type'));
  if ((data_type != 0)) {
    edited = true;
  } else {
    edited = false;
  }

  if (edited == true) {
    obj[i] = {};
    obj[i]['id'] = data_id;
    obj[i]['type'] = data_type;
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want an array instead...?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I saw same suggest in other post , but I don't get it why?

Comment: @AmitJoki can you explain more clear?

Comment: Also please cache the object: `for (var i = 0, len=$(".list").length;  i<len; i++)`

Comment: Because if you used an array the indexing would automatically start from zero and your problem would be solved.

Comment: Note that you're basically doing everything the hard way. Iterating over a jQuery collection using a `for` loop, getting the same collection multiple times and using `eq` instead of using one of the built in jQuery methods for iteration and `this`. Using `attr` to get the data attributes, as using `data` would coerce type automatically, and you wouldn't need `parseInt`, not that you need it at all, as you're doing non-strict testing, then using a variable to set `true/false`, then using that variable on the next line for another condition etc.

Comment: @user1775888 - my suggestion is to use array. but in case you stick on using object, you can refer to my answer :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you want to start in 0, use another variable and not "i" (which I think is 3 when you use it as index).

```
var obj = {};
var edited = false;
var obj_idx = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < $(".list").length; i++) {
  var data_id = parseInt($(".list").eq(i).attr('data-id'));
  var data_type = parseInt($(".list").eq(i).attr('data-type'));
  if ((data_type != 0)) {
    edited = true;
  } else {
    edited = false;
  }

  if (edited == true) {
    obj[obj_idx] = {};
    obj[obj_idx]['id'] = data_id;
    obj[obj_idx]['type'] = data_type;
    obj_idx += 1;
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

I think this time obj will be something like:

```
Object
  0: Object
     id: 34
     type: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Needs more jQuery ?

```
var arr = $(".list").filter(function() {
              return $(this).data('type') != 0;
          }).map(function() {
              return { id : $(this).data('id'), type : $(this).data('type') };
          }).get();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0k4czg10/)

Comment: what is the `get()` here?

Comment: @elaijuh - it converts the jQuery collection to an ordinary array

Comment: that's elegant, but need to consider browser compatibility especially for dear IE8 or lower by using `filter` and `map`?

Comment: @elaijuh - in this case, those are jQuery methods, and not the native methods, so that's not an issue

Answer (score 1):

you could fake object as array by `Array.prototype.push.call`, in that way you could also gain the side effect: `obj.length`. it's kinda ninja and elegant :]

```
var obj = {};
var edited = false;
for (var i = 0; i < $(".list").length; i++) {
  var data_id = parseInt($(".list").eq(i).attr('data-id'));
  var data_type = parseInt($(".list").eq(i).attr('data-type'));
  if ((data_type != 0)) {
    edited = true;
  } else {
    edited = false;
  }

  if (edited == true) {
    Array.prototype.push.call(obj, {id: data_id, type: data_type});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give a very simple and readable example. Say you've got an object with the following structure:

```
Object
  0: Object
     key: 'some-key'
     value: 'some-value'
  1: Object
     ...
```

Then you might want to delete an entry from it and reindex the whole thing, this is how I do it:

```
// obj is Object from above
const reIndexed = Object.entries(obj).map((element, index) => {
  if (parseInt(element[0] != index) {
    element[0] = index.toString();
  }
  return element;
});
```